# which server to use for android app

Tags: android, java-server

Motivation : I am trying to send mail to server in android . I want to build the server side. What type of server is suitable for that? I have a very few idea about server. So I need some reference . I am using smtp protocol .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a simple [LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29) server with the smtp host enabled?

Comment: LAMP is basically your standard non-windows web server, great for easily having ftp, e-mail, http, etc... out of the box with little to no configuration required.  It stands for Linux, Apache, MySQL and PHP.  The main take-away for you will be the Linux part.  I highly recommend using either Ubuntu, Debian or SUSE... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29#External_links